# Refresh UIScrollview

Tags: ios, scrollview

In my app, i'm using an `UIScrollView`. I am adding some subviews to it, but it takes a long time before the `UIScrollView` is (automatically) refreshing and the content I added will appear. Is there a method to do this manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding some subviews on `UIScrollView` on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to do it, the view is automatically refreshed when you add/modify subview

The manual way to "force" an update is through [UIVIew setNeedsDisplay] but this is more when you subclass a view and do custom drawing

On standard UIView/ScrollView this should not be needed, so may be your problem is somewhere else?